# Connector Current Carrying Capacity (circuits in paralllel)

Tags: current, connector, parallel

We have a production application where nominal current is  285mA and the connectors is only rated for 300mA capacity!

There are two additional circuits available so we may parallel two circuits for power and return.

How can we re-rate the connector current? What is the applicable standard? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not planning on hot connecting the connector, it is safe to simply multiply by the number of shared connections.

However, it is best of the shared pins are next to each other. Having them on different sides of say a ribbon cable creates loops that can cause noise issues.

Also, the quality of the connector makes a difference. Cheaper connectors may only make on one of the two pins leading to a higher current on the other. This should not be a problem in your case since the total current is under the maximum for a single pin.

Comment: can you cite a standard or other reference to that end? correct no hot plugging. thx!

Comment: @user1309285 standard? I am not aware of one... though you may find some application literature from connector vendors. This answer is just 40years experience and some very simple math.

Comment: for surgical robotics, I rather pursue standards and committees than personal experience and my motivated reasoning (and motivated calculating)! trying to reach the connector vendor for support. anything else i am missing?